# windows.h file not found when building for Android on windows

Tags: android, windows, qt

I have problem when I try to build my app with **Qt 5.14.2 static android kit**. I have seen similar errors while searching but didn't find solution.
I don't know why but I am getting this error in **rand.h** file inside **OpenSSL directory**:

```
fatal error: 'windows.h' file not found
#  include <windows.h>
```

I am on **Windows 10**

**Qt 5.14.2 Static**

**NDK version: 21.1.6352462**

Any suggestion or hint? Thanks in advance.

**Update**: Same error with normal(non static) **Qt 5.15.0**

Answer (score -1):

Yes, `#include <>` says search h-file in your filesystem. This line possible framed something like `#if Q_OS_...` or other close. Check compilation output for option `--target=`
Little more: you build application for Android on (as I guess) Windows. Qt need understand that app-OS not the same as now. Keyword is **crosscompilation**

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @IInspectable, I can add 'double check Qt creator settings' for TS but it will not answer still. I guess he don't understand what is problem. I explain it. In other word, next question is why Qt try include windows.h for android application?

Comment: @user123445151156, I see you localized #include error. Next - check framed `#If` `#endif` in file with error - how it decide with OS will be used? If OpenSSL building from source, you should build and link it for target platform, Android in your case.